# Convert query from MySql to Sqlite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I need to convert this query from MySQL format to SQLite. I'm trying myself but I've found some difficulty.

In SQLite, the curdate() and the interval functions do not exist.

```
select a.Date 
from (
    select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a
where a.Date between '2010-01-20' and '2010-01-24'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic syntax:

```
select a.Date 
from (select date('now', '-'||(a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a))|| ' days') as Date
      from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
           ) a cross join
           (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
           ) b cross join
           (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
           ) c
    ) a;
```

I left out the `where` clause because those dates are more than 1000 days in the past, so they won't select anything anyway.

Comment: Thanks!! I've checked your answer but I've decided to substitute the query with the query on the next answer because is better for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

What this query actually does is just generating lots of consecutive dates (up to one thousand previous days).

In SQLite 3.8.3 or later, this can be done more easily with a recursive [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(d)
AS (VALUES('2010-01-20')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date(d, '+1 day')
    FROM dates
    WHERE d < '2010-01-24')
SELECT d AS date FROM dates;
```

Comment: Thanks man!! you're awesome!! :)
I've checked the previous answer because he has answered my question but I think that your solution is better than my and I will take for my project! :)